# Prove that $\|u + v\| = \|u - v\|$ if and only if u and v are orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra

Note: $u$ and $v$ are vectors.

I am trying to using Pythagoras' theorem to prove this.

Pythagoras' theorem: $$\|u + v\|^2 = \|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2$$ if $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal AKA $u\cdot v = 0$.

My trouble is converting $\|u + v\|$ to $\|u - v\|$, could be something I am overthinking. This is for a first year university course.

Thanks.

(I cannot use theorems beyond what I've learned at this point / first year linear algebra)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<=

If $u,v$ are orthogonal vectors, then:
$$\| u + v \|^2 = \|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2$$
$$\| u - v \|^2 = \|u\|^2 + \|-v\|^2 = \|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2$$
now $\| u + v \|^2 = \| u - v \|^2$, but the norm is ever positive therefore:
$\| u + v \| = \| u - v \|$.

=> Now, if $\| u + v \| = \| u - v \|$ we have:

$\| u + v \|^2 = \|u\|^2 + 2u\cdot v + \|v\|^2$

$\| u - v \|^2 = \|u\|^2 - 2u\cdot v + \|v\|^2$

By the equality

$\|u\|^2 + 2u\cdot v + \|v\|^2 = \|u\|^2 - 2u\cdot v + \|v\|^2$ if and only if

$2u\cdot v = -2u\cdot v \Leftrightarrow 4u\cdot v = 0 \Leftrightarrow u\cdot v = 0$

this is $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal

Answer (score 1):

Use this
$$\|u + v\|^2 = \|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2 + 2 \Re(\langle u, v\rangle).$$

Comment: First year undergrad probably means that you don't need to worry about complex vector spaces, and $\Re$ might be confusing.

Comment: $u,v$ should be real. If $u=[-i,1],v=[1,i]$,then $||u+v||=||u-v||$ but $\langle u,v\rangle$ is not $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\|x\|^2=x\cdot x$ so $\|x+y\|^2=(x+y)\cdot (x+y)=x\cdot x + x\cdot y + y\cdot x + y\cdot y$, and similarly for $\|x-y\|^2$.

Answer (score 0):

cosine rule gives you  $|u+v|^2 = |u|^2 + |v|^2 + 2u^Tv$  and 
$|u-v|^2 = |u|^2 + |v|^2 - 2u^Tv$
so if
$|u+v|^2 = |u-v|^2 $ then  $u^Tv = 0$

Comment: Um, no, that should be $|u+v|^2+|u-v|^2$. You've got Appollonius wrong.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks for spotting the error.